# Using password protected ssh keys

Tags: jenkins

If you use password-protected SSH keys, is there a way to pass the password at the command line automatically instead of manually typing it?

E.g. something like:

`ssh-add <key> -p password`

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/).

- Ubuntu/Debian: `apt-get install sshpass`
- Fedora/CentOS: `yum install sshpass`

---

**Example:**

```
sshpass -p "YOUR_PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no YOUR_USERNAME@SOME_SITE.COM
```

**Custom port example:**

```
sshpass -p "YOUR_PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no YOUR_USERNAME@SOME_SITE.COM:2400
```

**Notes:**

- `sshpass` can also read a password from a file when the `-f` flag is passed.

  - Using `-f` prevents the password from being visible if the `ps` command is executed.
  - The file that the password is stored in should have secure permissions.

Answer (score 0):

But storeing your password in a command is not the best way - it should be better to remove the password for this case - so you do not reveal your key password

```
$ ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
```